# Discrepancies in gensim doc2vec embedding vectors

Tags: gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I use gensim Doc2Vec package to train doc2vec embeddings. I would expect that two models trained with the identical parameters and data would have very close values of the doc2vec vectors. However, in my experience it is only true with doc2vec trained in the PV-DBOW without training word embedding (dbow_words = 0).
For PV-DM and for PV-DBOW with dbow_words = 1, i.e. every case the word embedding are trained along with doc2vec, the doc2vec embedding vectors for identically trained models are fairly different.

Here is my code

```py
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
    from gensim import models
    import scipy.spatial.distance as distance
    import numpy as np
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from string import punctuation
    def clean_text(texts,  min_length = 2):
        clean = []
        #don't remove apostrophes
        translator = str.maketrans(punctuation.replace('\'',' '), ' '*len(punctuation))
        for text in texts:
            text = text.translate(translator)
            tokens = text.split()
            # remove not alphabetic tokens
            tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
            # filter out stop words
            stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
            tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
            # filter out short tokens
            tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) >= min_length]
            tokens = ' '.join(tokens)
            clean.append(tokens)
        return clean
    def tag_text(all_text, tag_type =''):
        tagged_text = []
        for i, text in enumerate(all_text):
            tag = tag_type + '_' + str(i)
            tagged_text.append(models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(text.split(), [tag]))
        return tagged_text

    def train_docvec(dm, dbow_words, min_count, epochs, training_data):
        model = models.Doc2Vec(dm=dm, dbow_words = dbow_words, min_count = min_count)
        model.build_vocab(tagged_data)
        model.train(training_data, total_examples=len(training_data), epochs=epochs)    
        return model

    def compare_vectors(vector1, vector2):
        cos_distances = []
        for i in range(len(vector1)):
            d = distance.cosine(vector1[i], vector2[i])
            cos_distances.append(d)
        print (np.median(cos_distances))
        print (np.std(cos_distances))    

    dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, random_state=1,remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
    n_samples = len(dataset.data)
    data = clean_text(dataset.data)
    tagged_data = tag_text(data)
    data_labels = dataset.target
    data_label_names = dataset.target_names

    model_dbow1 = train_docvec(0, 0, 4, 30, tagged_data)
    model_dbow2 = train_docvec(0, 0, 4, 30, tagged_data)
    model_dbow3 = train_docvec(0, 1, 4, 30, tagged_data)
    model_dbow4 = train_docvec(0, 1, 4, 30, tagged_data)
    model_dm1 = train_docvec(1, 0, 4, 30, tagged_data)
    model_dm2 = train_docvec(1, 0, 4, 30, tagged_data)

    compare_vectors(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow2.docvecs)
    > 0.07795828580856323
    > 0.02610614028793008

    compare_vectors(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow3.docvecs)
    > 0.6476179957389832
    > 0.14797587172616306

    compare_vectors(model_dbow3.docvecs, model_dbow4.docvecs)
    > 0.19878000020980835
    > 0.06362519480831186

    compare_vectors(model_dm1.docvecs, model_dm2.docvecs)
    > 0.13536489009857178
    > 0.045365127475424386

    compare_vectors(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dm1.docvecs)
    > 0.6358324736356735
    > 0.15150255674571805
```

> UPDATE

I tried, as suggested by gojomo, to compare the differences between the vectors, and, unfortunately, those are even worse:

```py
def compare_vector_differences(vector1, vector2):
    diff1 = []
    diff2 = []
    for i in range(len(vector1)-1):
        diff1.append( vector1[i+1] - vector1[i])
    for i in range(len(vector2)-1):
        diff2[i].append(vector2[i+1] - vector2[i])
    cos_distances = []
    for i in range(len(diff1)):
        d = distance.cosine(diff1[i], diff2[i])
        cos_distances.append(d)
    print (np.median(cos_distances))
    print (np.std(cos_distances))    

compare_vector_differences(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow2.docvecs)
> 0.1134452223777771
> 0.02676398444178949

compare_vector_differences(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow3.docvecs)
> 0.8464127033948898
> 0.11423789350773429

compare_vector_differences(model_dbow4.docvecs, model_dbow3.docvecs)

> 0.27400463819503784
> 0.05984108730423529
```

> SECOND UPDATE

This time, after I finally understood gojomo, the things look fine.

```py
def compare_distance_differences(vector1, vector2):
    diff1 = []
    diff2 = []
    for i in range(len(vector1)-1):
        diff1.append( distance.cosine(vector1[i+1], vector1[i]))
    for i in range(len(vector2)-1):
        diff2.append( distance.cosine(vector2[i+1], vector2[i]))
    diff_distances = []
    for i in range(len(diff1)):
        diff_distances.append(abs(diff1[i] - diff2[i]))
    print (np.median(diff_distances))
    print (np.std(diff_distances))    

compare_distance_differences(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow2.docvecs)
>0.017469733953475952
>0.01659284710785352

compare_distance_differences(model_dbow1.docvecs, model_dbow3.docvecs)
>0.0786697268486023
>0.06092163158218411

compare_distance_differences(model_dbow3.docvecs, model_dbow4.docvecs)
>0.02321992814540863
>0.023095123172320778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc-vectors (or word-vectors) of `Doc2Vec` & `Word2Vec` models are only meaningfully comparable to other vectors that were co-trained, in the same interleaved training sessions.

Otherwise, randomness introduced by the algorithms (random-initialization & random-sampling) and by slight differences in training ordering (from multithreading) will cause the trained positions of individual vectors to wander to arbitrarily different positions. Their *relative* distances/directions, to other vectors that shared interleaved training, should be about as equally-useful from one model to the next.

But there's no one right place for such a vector, and measuring the differences between the vector for document '1' (or word 'foo') in one model, and the corresponding vector in another model, isn't reflective of anything the models/algorithms are trained to provide.

There's more information in the Gensim FAQ:

[Q11: I've trained my Word2Vec/Doc2Vec/etc model repeatedly using the exact same text corpus, but the vectors are different each time. Is there a bug or have I made a mistake?](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/recipes-&-faq#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense, along the lines of "king - man + woman = queen" logic. I computed the differences between the vectors, not all just the consecutive ones (see above). Unfortunately, the distances between the differences are even greater. What am I missing?

Comment: The way in which the models should be similar – if sufficiently trained with adequate data/metaparameters – is that things like the rank  order of nearest neighbors are very similar, or downstream applications analogy solving (like `king - man + woman ~~= queen`) succeeds at roughly similar rates. It is not the case that either individual word-positions, or relative directions between word-positions, will be aligned.

Comment: Your updated test still calculates **directional vectors** in 1 model (eg `model1[king] - model1[man]`) & checks if for cosine-similarity (same-direction) as directional vectors in another (`model2[king] - model2[man]`). There's nothing in the usual training, or expectations about a working model or effective training, that would force 2 **models** to be similar that way. (Training could be further constrained, or vectors post-processed, to force such alignment – but it's not a normal property of multiple `Word2Vec` models, & so their divergence is not necessarily an indicator of any problem.)

Comment: Instead, `model1[king] - model1[man]` need not be alike `model2[king] - model2[man]`, just as `model1[queen]` is not alike to `model2[queen]` nor is `model1[woman]` alike to `model2[woman]`. **But**, in each model's transformed (rotated/reflected/scaled/etc) coordinates, given sufficient data/parameters, the full `king - man + woman` direction should wind up near `queen`. And the same should be the case for other downstream applications, like doc-classification or info-retrieval – whose optimal training parameters aren't always the same as those optimal for analogy-solving.